# c# - How to create a custom dictionary for SpeechRecognizer?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I am using the following code to create a speech recognizer but I only want it to recognize 3 things, which is a drivers license, a postal code and a date in formats

```
M1234-56789-01234
L9B 2X5
yyyy/mm/dd
```

I don't care about these characters '/', ' ', '-'. (As in they shouldn't be included in the text that the recognizer recognizes).

I only care about the alphabets and digits.

I created a grammar with only digits and alphabets, but when talking, the recognizer creates words like 'TO' or 'THERE'. Is there a way to restrict to only recognize individual letters and numbers?

```
        SpeechRecognizer sr = new SpeechRecognizer();

        Choices chars = new Choices();
        chars.Add(new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" });

        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Append(chars);

        // Create the Grammar instance.
        Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);

        sr.LoadGrammar(g);

        sr.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sr_SpeechRecognized);
```

Comment: Does your recognizer recognize phrase `to 2012/02/12` as `['to', '2', '0', '1', '2', '0', '2', '1', '2']`?

Comment: sometimes saying "two" it creates the number 2, and sometimes it creates the word "to". So I was wondering if there is a way to give a custom dictionary, so it can only output those words (which are individual letters and numbers)

Comment: Grammars are the way to restrict what the speech recognition engine recognizes. I am confused as to why it is returning items that are "out of grammar".  Is the ASR indicating that these are out of grammar or does it think it has a valid recognition? Have you tried tried spelling the numbers in your grammar ("zero", "one", "two", ...)?